# Getting all my check-ins from a single category via Foursquare's API

Tags: api, foursquare

So here's what I'm trying to do: I have a space on my website that says X cups of coffee. Ideally the X would be replaced with the number of times I have checked into a venue on Foursquare that falls under the coffee shop category. Right now, I have to manually update the number from my site's backend. This is just too much work, and I'd rather be able to check-in and have the Foursquare API update the number automatically. Is this possible, and if so, what would be the easiest way to execute it?

Thanks so much in advance for your suggestions and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the realtime push API to notify your server whenever you check in on Foursquare. You can then use the information in the check-in to update statistics on your website.

Here is the documentation for the push API: https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/realtime

Comment: Thanks for your response! I noticed that an SSL certificate is required. Since I'm just implementing this on a simple personal portfolio site, I'm not currently set up with an SSL. Is there any way to get around that?

Comment: Since a user's private data is sent through the push API, your server must be able to handle HTTPS requests. It is okay if your certificate is self-signed, but you must have one.